# MAC : bash script which invokes a Python script , both these scripts are in the same directory

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell

I have written a bash script in MAC , which is placed in a directory say xyz.
Now i have a python file in the same directory xyz

We can also say that this python script will always be in the directory where this bash script is

So i want this bash script to be general

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/labuser/Desktop/Installer/OpenURL_GenericNotification.py Some Arguments

So i want to replace 
/Users/labuser/Desktop/Installer/
so that from wherever this script is run python script is automatically calculated by some system variable like $cd 
/Users/labuser/Desktop/Installer/ this like $cd in windows not sure how in MAC
Any comments on how to go about this script ??

Comment: Why specifically python 3.5?  What if the user only has, say, 2.7 installed? And if all the script is doing is invoking the python script then it's adding no value at all.

Comment: Reason Being , the script i have written , has some imports which are not availaible to Python 2.7 http.client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Bash script, the path to the script is stored in the `$0` variable.

The `dirname` command returns the directory portion of a path (filename removed).

You can use the `dirname` with `$0` to get the script's base directory, and `cd` to that path, and then run the Python script in the current directory:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

./OpenURL_GenericNotification.py
```